# How to add a hotkey for Suggestions in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I would like the Suggestion Widget to popup with the use of a hotkey, preferable alt+space. However, I cannot find what setting I need to change in order to achieve this. I tried looking through all of the key settings for: "widget", "suggestions"

I find this important because when you try to import an additional function/class from a module in typescript you need to know what you are looking for. I just want the suggestion widget to show and it annoys me that I can't do that.

```
import {  } from './module1'
```

Any solvers?

[image]

Note: Not looking for code correction hotkey

Comment: It is ctrl+space by default. Knowing that you can now search by hotkey

Comment: Thank you Patrick! I did try ctrl+space and it still isn't working for some odd reason. I did switch it to alt+space and that works great! For others information, I'm using OSX Mojave